# Find the number of APs which can be formed from given set $S$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

Find the number of arithmetic progressions, which can be formed from the elements of $S$, which begin with $1$ and end with $400$ and have at least $3$ elements.
$$S = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 400\}$$

Here's how I proceeded with the above question:

> Given min length of AP as $3$, we can have $d$ from $1$ to $199$.
>
> 1. With $d=1$ and APs from length $3$ to $400$, we have $398+397+...+1$ APs.
>
> 2. With $d=2$ and APs from length $3$ to $399$, we have $396+394+...+2$ APs.
>
> 3. With $d=3$ and APs from length $3$ to $398$, we have $394+391+...+1$ APs.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 199. With $d=199$ and APs from length $3$ to $3$, we have $2$ APs.
>
> Sadly, this is not a nice enough pattern as you can observe from 2. and 3. that the end-points vary for different common-differences, d and don't really fall into a pattern (not that I could observe). So I left it at that.

But then when I saw the solution, it stumped me! Here it is:

> Let the number of elements be denoted by n. Let the common difference be denoted by d.
>  $$1 + (n – 1) d = 400$$
>  $$\Rightarrow (n – 1) d = 399 = 3(7) (19)$$
>  $$\Rightarrow n – 1 \text { as well as d must be factors of }399, \text {but as }n ≥ 3, n – 1 ≥ 2$$
>  $$∴ (n – 1, d) = (3, 133), (7, 57), (19, 21), (21, 19), (57, 7), (133, 3)\text { or }(399, 1)$$
>  $$\text {∴ Number of arithmetic progressions, which can be formed = }7.$$
>  Here, I was stumped at $1 + (n – 1) d = 400$ itself. Didn't make sense to me.

This question is a contest-math question as well, so it really shouldn't consume a lot of time, perhaps, $10-15$ mins at the extreme end in case you're too good with other questions and so have so much time left. Please help me with the problem and which approach, if they are, is correct?

Comment: " I was stumped at $1+(n–1)d=400$ itself"..The nth term of an AP is given by $a+(n–1)d $ where a is the first term and d is the common difference.

Comment: @HaHa that I know but what's the use of it. In the solution, it's used in a way that doesn't at all covers the various possibilities in which an AP can be formed.

Comment: They did it to use the fact that n–1 as well as d must be factors of 399,

Comment: Also,can you kindly point out which AP possibilty is missing ?

Comment: Oh, sure, these APs are as follows: <p>
1. with d=1: 1,2,3 ; 2,3,4 ; ... ; 398,399,400; 1,2,3,4 ; 2,3,4,5 ; ... ; 397,398,399,400 ; ... ;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....,400 <p> 
2. with d=2: 2,4,6 ; 4,6,8 ; ... ; 396,398,400; 2,4,6,8 ; 4,6,8,10 ; ... 394,396,398,400 ; ... ; 2,4,6,8,...,400 <p>
and so on to finally arrive at <p>
199. with d=199: 1,200,399 ; 2,201,400

Comment: Not all of your examples begin with $1$ and end with $400$, as required.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig that solves it! Thanks a lot! I'm actually misreading a lot! is there a way not to do it?

Comment: When you read mathematics, read slowly and carefully.  You need to read mathematics much more slowly than other subjects so that you do not miss the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect since you considered arithmetic progressions that do not begin with $1$ and end with $400$.

The requirement that the arithmetic sequence begins with $1$ implies that $a_1 = 1$.  The requirement that the $n$-term arithmetic sequence ends with $400$ implies that $a_n = 400 = a_1 + (n - 1)d = 1 + (n - 1)d$.

Hence, $(n - 1)d = 399$.  Since the elements of the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 400\}$ are integers, $n - 1$ and $d$ must be factors of $399$.  Since $399 = 3 \cdot 133 = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$, any factor of $399$ must be of the form $3^\alpha 7^\beta 13^\gamma$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \{0, 1\}$.  That gives $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$ possible values for $n - 1$.  They are $1, 3, 7, 19, 21, 57, 133, 399$. The requirement that the arithmetic progression contains at least three terms means $n \geq 3 \implies n - 1 \geq 2$. That eliminates $n - 1 = 1$, so there are seven possible values of $n - 1$, namely $3, 7, 19, 21, 57, 133, 399$.  Consequently, there are seven possible arithmetic progressions in set $S$ which begin with $1$ and end with $400$.